# Date manipulation in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

Hello I have DataFrame with clients' agreements like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ "ID" : ["1", "2", "1", "2", "2"], "Date": rng})
```

And I need to create new DataFrame with calculation based on above df:

Column1= number of days from the first agreement until today (18.12)

Column2 = numberof days from the last agreement until today (18.12)

To be more precision I need to create df like below:

[image]

Comment: you have two ID 2 which is 12/04 and 12/05 , which one you would like keep

Comment: for each ID I need to have number of days from the last and form the earlier date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `groupby`

```
out = df.groupby('ID').Date.agg(['min','max']).rsub(pd.to_datetime('2020-12-18'))
       min     max
ID                
1  17 days 15 days
2  16 days 13 days
```

Comment: Thank you Benny, it looks good, but is it possible to remove "days"? because in the output i have for instance 17 days?

Comment: @rumor154 df.groupby('ID').Date.agg(['min','max']).rsub(pd.to_datetime('2020-12-18')).apply(lambda x :x.dt.days)